# Защита от взлома базы данных (перец)

Tags: java, postgresql, kotlin, spring-boot, spring-jdbc

Мне предстояла задача защитить данные от подделки на случай взлома или угона базы данных (postgres).
Есть таблица которая защищает `urls` для доступа по ролям (примерно как spring-boot security).
В таблице колонки:
`path`: защищенный путь /account
`roles`: массив ролей {admin,user}
`hash`: верификация данных (roles + pepper)

Я не просто так дописал `pepper` для `roles`.
Исходя из моей задумки, в коде веб-приложения(не доступный хакеру), зашит перец для хэша, который состоит из массива ролей + сам перец.

Необратимый хэш формируется в коде непосредственно перед вставкой в базу.

При обращении к защищенному `url` происходит проверка указанных ролей и хэша на их основе.

Если хакер угоняет базу, то это не страшно, но если он найдет дыру для инжекта, и например добавляется/изменяется роль на более доступную, например `guest`, то запрос сразу считается невалидным. Тоже самое и с хэшем.

Предположительно хакер не сможет сгенерировать новый хэш с новыми ролями, так у него нету перца. Соответсвенно взлом невозможен. Или возможен?

Мне сложно здесь описать всю логику, но она уже сделана и работает.

Если вы сможете понять, пожалуйста укажите мне на ошибки моего подхода или это вообще бессмысленно и есть гораздо более грубые методы взлома.

Еще раз: моя задача была защитить от инжекта таблицу с урлами, которые защищенны доступом по ролям.

Comment: то есть, по сути, вы изобретаете [хеш функцию для электронной подписи](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%AD%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C#%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%85%D0%B5%D1%88-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9).

Comment: @tym32167 да, наверное вы правы, что-то очень похоже на ЭЛ. Наверно это даже и велосипед. Хочется узнать у людей которые реализовывали такое у себя. Насколько это правильно и эффективно

Comment: Разве в этой схеме нельзя взять hash из другой существующей записи с нужными ролями и изменить, в той которую хочется подделать?

Comment: @RomanKonoval я могу сказать только то, что гоняясь за мухами не заметил слона). Да, действительно, не подумал, но это не проблема если в хэш я зашью еще и id записи. Кроме этих колонок там еще масса других, таких как дата создания, enable, owner итд. Просто я не могу создать хэш на основе их всех ввиду ограничения на рамер байтов в моем криптографе - 71 байт

Comment: так тоже самое будет. меняем id в записях. нужно зашивать path

Comment: @RomanKonoval я дополнил коммент выше. Я бы с радостью зашил туда все, но не могу. Других методов крипты я пока не пробовал, использую самый медленный с кучей соли Bcrypt.

Comment: @RomanKonoval тоесть path + roles + pepper? здесь мне придется жертвовать многим, ну или менять тип данных в колонках с varchar на int для экономии, как вариант. Если у вас есть еще мысли, дайте пожалуйста развернутый ответ

Comment: Вообще-то нормально не держать всё в одной базе. Тогда угнав какойто кусок он может смело сунуть его поглубже. И ещё для работы с распределенной базой нужно будет достать приложение и настроить его так что оно работало. Разделяй и властвовуй

Comment: @AzizUmarov тоесть можно создать отдельную базу например для хэшей? с той же иерархией что и основная. Только у меня не было опыта с "разделяй и властвуй" и я пока что не понимаю чем мне это поможет )

Comment: Вот для вашего примера угнав роли он якобы получит доступ. К чему? Если у вас нет в этой базе явного указания чья эта роль, только цифры. Ему нужно будет достать базу пользователей и смапить роли с пользователями. И наоборот достав пользователей откуда он узнает какая роль если их там нет и вот так разделяете приватные данные да так чтобы злоумышленнику приходилось доставать ещё данные.

Comment: Пример. Есть банк. Данные в одном, счета в другом, транзакции в третьем месте. Достав каждую он не сможет собрать воедино. Конечно это создаст неудобства и для вас, но если вам не нужно будет делать запросы по типу всё про всех то проблем не будет.